# Ionic Native: tried calling FileOpener.open, but the FileOpener plugin is not installed.

Tags: plugins, ionic2, fileopener2

**WARN**

*Ionic Native: tried calling FileOpener.open, but the FileOpener plugin is not installed. 
Install the FileOpener plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-opener2'*

**Already make all the necessary modifications and the problem persists.**

**Here is the repository.**

[enter link description here](https://github.com/yhyenifer/chart-pdf_ionic)

Any idea Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please make sure your title is a question, and try to include more info. For instance: "all the necessary modifications "? Also, your link doesn't have a proper link description.

Comment: npm install --save @ionic-native/file-opener did?

Comment: yes npm install --save @ionic-native/file-opener

Comment: Is the problem is happening in iOS or in Android too ?

Answer (score 0):

May be you are facing version issue.i am also face this issue ionic -3. i change the version it working fine

To open existing PDF file, you can use File Opener plugin. 
First install the Cordova and Ionic Native plugins:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-opener2
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/file-opener
```